# What happened to the revives?!? They're gone! How can I get more?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

So, I today, when I opened the app, I noticed a few things different:

- Some minor text fixes ("The Stash" was renamed to "Shop") and
- All the utilities but mission unlocks and Final Blasts are missing

[image: No revives]

(Yep, that's the entirety of the Utilities section of the store; the stash)

What happened to the revives?!?
It doesn't seem to have been locked behind a paywall as the "Purchase Coins" menu did not have any revives in it.

More specifically, how do I get the 5-packs? They're 6,000 coins each and are cheaper than purchasing them one-by-one t 1,500 coins each, thus not getting one free every time.

I'm on iOS and checking the App Store, it doesn't seem to report that there was any changes between now and yesterday, where they were still available for purchase...

Edit: After checking out the Android version of the game, it seems to have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Halfbrick has said it again and again, the quick revives are not gone, they are just moved to the end of a run (short answer: when you die you can purchase quick revives). As to how you get the 5-packs.... I would very much like to know that myself.